# How to validate user login after the first login in an Android app created through Apache Cordova (UI is on SAPUI5)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5

I am creating an android application using Apache Cordova and my UI is on SAPUI5,is there any way where I can store the user login credentials securely so that user doesn't need to enter user id and password again until he perform logout operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for a similar answer for months.  I came up with 2 options, one of which was not so secure.

The best answer was to generate a session token and store that token in localStorage.  The login would see if the session token is valid and bypass login if it is.

The other, not so secure, option was to hash and save the login information in the localStorage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello David,that's a good idea , but when the user uninstalls the application without doing logout ,does the table we created on login get erased itself or we need to do by code. Thanks for help.

Comment: When the user uninstalls the app it will remove all data stored on the device.